# How to run crontab for every 36 hours

Tags: php, cron

I am creating Automated cron tab using php. i need to run this cron tab for following times.

24 hours or
36 hours or
48 hours or 
72 hours or
96 hours.

i am confused to setup in cron tab for 36 hours.

How do I set up a cronjob that runs every 36th hours? Please Advise

Comment: You'll have to set up multiple jobs for different timespans, all running the same job. There's no way to directly tell cron "every 36 hours", because the hours range in a cron definition is maximum 23 hours.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can specify further than 24 hours.

You could have it run every hour, and each time it hits have it increment a var stored in a database or file, then when that var hits 36 run the script and reset it to 1.

EDIT: on the same note you could have it run every 12 hours and have it increment by 12

for example :

```
$var = (int) file_get_contents('count.txt'); 
$var++;
if($var === 36) {
   //run script
   //update count.txt
}else {
   //update count.txt
   die(); 
}
```

Comment: ok thanks for your quick replay. i can try this and i can update you

Answer (score 2):

It's not a great solution, but...

Set the cron job up to run the script every 12 hours.  In the script, add something like:

```
$hour_of_year = date('z') * 24 + date('H');

if ($hour_of_year % 36 == 0) {
    // RUN THE PROGRAM

} else {
    // DONT RUN THE PROGRAM
}
```

Comment: ok thanks for your replay. i can try this and i can update you

Answer (score 2):

To schedule a cron job to run every 36 hours just use two strings:

```
0 0 0,3,6,9,12,15,18,21,24,27,30 * *
0 12 1,4,7,10,13,16,19,22,25,28 * *
```

Comment: Does not take into account month-end roll-over to next month for long/short months and leap years though.