# Cron for 2.5 Days

Tags: cron, whenever

I've searched for this but cant seem to find an answer. I was reading the following post
[Cron Job for Every 3 days](https://blog.nexcess.net/2014/02/06/cron-job-for-every-three-days/) 
which is almost what i need:

> The command for “day of the year” is
>
> `date +%-j`
>
> Where the hyphen before the “j” means “don’t pad” (with zeros in this
>   case – so we can use it as a number). Now we just check if this is
>   evenly divisible by three by using the modulo – % – which returns the
>   remainder of dividing.
>
> `$(( 'date +%-j' % 3 ))`
>
> The $(( )) part tells bash to perform a calculation, and the backticks
>   are there to run our date command separately from the rest. So if this
>   calculation is zero, we have a winner.
>
> `[ $(( 'date +%-j' % 3 )) == 0 ]`
>
> Remember, though, we need an offset so that we start on the 1st. The
>   way it is currently, it starts on the 3rd. Just by subtracting one
>   from the day of the year, we can get everything to line up. We have to
>   wrap that calculation with $(( )) as well.
>
> `[ $((  $(( 'date +%-j' - 1 )) % 3 )) == 0 ]`
>
> That test fulfills our conditions so our full crontab entry would be:
>
> `30 05 * * * [ $((  $(( 'date +%-j' - 1 )) % 3 )) == 0 ] && execute_this`

However i have a specific case to run this every 2.5 days. Is this not at all possible in cron? Is it a matter of switching the 3 our for 2.5 or not?

i know i can do 2 and a half hours by specifying minutes instead, but 2.5 days?

For information I'm using the [Whenever Gem](https://github.com/javan/whenever) in a Ruby on Rails application, but may have to edit cron manually.

Any advice here is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run crontab for every 36 hours](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17726620/how-to-run-crontab-for-every-36-hours)

Comment: i'm going to try the solution by johnnyfaldo from that post then. however 2 questions related to it. 1. what would happen if the server went down for a period and 2. what would happen at the end of the month? would the counter carry on as expected.

Comment: Well, it's not my speciality, but I wouldn't count on a counter in this instance.  This here sounds like a more sophisticated solution perhaps http://askubuntu.com/questions/646684/how-to-run-a-cron-job-every-36-hours

Comment: ok thanks for that. i'll take a look. i have an instance that i want to run every 89 hours. woe is me

Comment: Those are some curious requirements, all parts of the joys of programming I guess.